# How can I be informed that the UI has been redrawn in Android?

Tags: android, events, user-interface, notifications

Hey guys... My application requires that I be informed of any changes to the UI of my application. Is there anyway that I can be informed of this? Perhaps through means of an event or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the onDraw() method of View. Something like

```
public class MyView extends View{
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.d("MyView", "onDraw() called");
    }
...
```